# How can I get the probability given the Bayesian table?

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

Consider that $A \rightarrow B$. And A has two states 0 and 1 respectively with probability of $0.6$ and $0.4$. 
$$
\mbox{And for}\ B:
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
{\displaystyle Pr\left(B = 1 \mid A = 1\right)} & {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle  0.3}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle Pr\left(B = 1 \mid A = 0\right)} & {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle  0.2}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle Pr\left(B = 0 \mid A = 1\right)} & {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle  0.7}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle Pr\left(B = 0 \mid A = 0\right)} & {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle  0.8}
\end{array}\right.
$$

What I want to get is $Pr(B=1)$, and I know the result is $\frac{0.3+0.2}{0.3+0.2+0.7+0.8}$. But my question is how can I get the result provided the two tables?

My reduction:

$$
\begin{align}
Pr(B=1) &= \frac{Pr(B=1|A)}{Pr(B=1|A) + Pr(B=0|A)}\\   
& = \frac{\frac{Pr(B=1,A)}{Pr(A)}}{\frac{Pr(B=1,A)}{Pr(A)}+\frac{Pr(B=0,A)}{Pr(A)}} \\
& = \frac{Pr(B=1, A=0) + Pr(B=1, A=1)}{Pr(B=1, A=0) + Pr(B=1, A=1) + Pr(B=0, A=0) + Pr(B=0, A=1)}
\end{align}
$$

Am I right?

Any hints or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: $Pr(B = 1) = \frac{Pr(B=1}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{1}Pr(B = i)}$. Its essentially the "area" of $B = 1$ divided by the entire "area". Note that you need to take into account both cases $A = 0$ and $A = 1$ when computing $Pr(B = i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the result is $\frac{0.3+0.2}{0.3+0.2+0.7+0.8}$

It is not right and it must be:
$$\begin{align}P(B=1)=&P(B=1,A=0)+P(B=1,A=1)=\\
=&P(A=0)\cdot P(B=1|A=0)+P(A=1)\cdot P(B=1|A=1)=\\
=&0.6\cdot 0.2+0.4\cdot 0.3=\\
=&0.24.\end{align}$$

Comment: Amazing! Great!

Comment: You are right. I have read the textbook and find this: The joint distribution of two random variables has to be consistent with the marginal distribution, in that $P(x)=\sum_y P(x, y)$. It seems very intuitive. What I was thinking was totally of non-sense. I was just applying the equations mechanically and unfortunately wrongly.